# Creating a Windows Restore Point?

Tags: vb.net, wmi

So I have this code, and am running into some issues that I haven't so far been able to sort out:

Anywhere there are Parameters, i.e. `"CreateRestorePoint"`, or the `inParams` params, I get the green squiggly underline that says to use (ex.) `"NameOf(CreateRestorePoint) instead of specifying the program element name"`.

**However, whether I do so or leave it, I get the same error:**

`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: path'`

**The code:**

```
    Public Function CreateRestorePoint(Description As String, EventType As Integer, RestorePointType As Integer) As Integer

        Try

            Dim classInstance As New ManagementObject("root\DEFAULT", "SystemRestore", Nothing)

            ' Obtain [in] parameters for the method
            Dim inParams As ManagementBaseObject = classInstance.GetMethodParameters("CreateRestorePoint")

            ' Add the input parameters
            inParams("Description") = Description
            inParams("EventType") = EventType
            inParams("RestorePointType") = RestorePointType

            ' Execute the method and obtain the return values
            Dim outParams As ManagementBaseObject = classInstance.InvokeMethod("CreateRestorePoint", inParams, Nothing)

            ' List outParams
            Debug.Print("Out parameters: ")
            Debug.Print("ReturnValue: {0}", outParams("ReturnValue"))

            CreateRestorePoint = 1

        Catch err As ManagementException

            Debug.Print(String.Format("An error occurred while trying to execute the WMI method: {0}", err.Message))

        End Try

        Return CreateRestorePoint

    End Function
```

**Here's how I'm calling  the function:**

```
    Dim CRP As New JSEWindowsRestore.WindowsRestoreFunctions

    CRP.CreateRestorePoint(String.Format("Test Restore Point: {0}", DateTime.Now), 100, 12)
```

Anyone spot the problem?

Comment: Which line does the error happen on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything looks pretty good.  The only thing that you need to change is ManagementObject in the first couple lines to ManagementClass.

```
Dim classInstance As New ManagementClass("root\DEFAULT", "SystemRestore", Nothing)
```

ManagementObject refers to an instance of a class and ManagementClass refers to the class itself.  The `path` error you were receiving was because the code was expecting a path to an instance and not a class itself.

As for the green squiggly lines, they shouldn't prevent you from compiling but its possible Visual Studio will like this syntax better.

```
        inParams.Properties("Description").Value = Description
        inParams.Properties("EventType").Value = EventType
        inParams.Properties("RestorePointType").Value = RestorePointType
```

Also, make sure the application has administrator privileges or you'll get an access denied when you try to invoke this method.

Comment: Why a downvote here? This information is correct. Possibly partial, nonetheless this is the direct problem with the OP's code.

Comment: It could be added that is possibly necessary to set a [ConnectionOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.connectionoptions) object, defining the access privileges and the impersonation type. The call will then be `Dim conOptions As ConnectionOptions = New ConnectionOptions() conOptions.EnablePrivileges = True conOptions.Authentication = Management.AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy Dim classInstance As New ManagementClass("root\DEFAULT", "SystemRestore", New ObjectGetOptions(conOptions.Context))`

Comment: @Jimi and Paul G thanks guys, still not working with all the recommended changes though. I now get this: https://i.imgur.com/622NpSV.png (also note that unfortunately, the green squiggly lines still persist; I know it still allows compiling, but it still drives the OCD in me crazy, LOL) (P.S. Wasn't me that downvoted!)

Comment: @J. Scott Elblein  This usually means that your Volume Shadow Copies (VSS) service and/or Microsoft Software Shadow Copy Provider (swprv) is/are not running or runnable.

Comment: @J.ScottElblein can you tell us more about your setup?  What OS are you on?  What type of Project is it (Console, winform, web app) and what framework? (.NET, .NET Core... what version?).  Also, what is the exact COM exception you're getting?  COM exceptions are cryptic at best but may help us figure out whats wrong.

Comment: @jimi Both of those services were set to manual (and weren't running, so I started them up and tried again; same error unfortunately. Paul, the exact error is just a blank string, lol. Here's a screenshot of the callstack, etc. if it helps (https://i.imgur.com/O9FTS3K.png). I'm coding this on Win 10 x64 Pro, in a VmWare VM. It's a WinForm project using .NET Framework 4.6.2.

Comment: It wont work which I knew already, theres more to do than the posted solution starting with Win8... I myself have a solution, but figuring out the second part has been a nitemare... It has to do with creating a reg key. The following will apply by default if the key does not exist. If an application calls the CreateRestorePoint method to create a restore point, Windows skips creating this new restore point if any restore points have been created in the last 24 hours. The CreateRestorePoint method returns S_OK. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sr/createrestorepoint-systemrestore

Comment: IMHO theres much info missing, as I mentioned I have a solution that runs, but the second part I havent got down just yet, I want to provide a full solution as you're going to run into it either way... Also to confirm that Volume Shadow Copies (VSS) , is on, manually create a backup, if it works its on...

Comment: @Jimi is most likely 100% correct on this Windows error -2147023838 (0x80070422) translates to SERVICE_DISABLED.  Open a cmd prompt and type "sc qc vss" to check the status of the Volume Shadow Copies service. make sure START_TYPE is not disabled.

Comment: Ok guys, I discovered the issue. Even though I had manually started both of the mentioned services, and tried several times, double and triple checking, I went to the properties sheet (https://i.imgur.com/JEySaDB.png) and saw that it was turned Off (doh!). After turning it on, and doing a few "successful" restores, nothing was showing up in the actual restore points section to select a point to restore. But then a few minutes later, 1 popped up. Very strange. I have also read some rumblings about the regkey that @codexer mentions; perhaps that had something to do with the latter's weirdness?

Comment: @J. Scott Elblein  You need to re-read the Docs about `RestorePoints` creations. You are by now *initiating* a `RestorePoint`. The system is smart enough to complete it for you if you don't take further action. Also, there are different types of `RestorePoint`. Read about them, too.